# Dúvida com lógica: Como descobrir se uma hora está entre o intervalo de horas (independente do dia)

Tags: php, mysql

Independente da hora que for, preciso descobrir se um horário está entre o intervalo de uma hora inicial e final, tendo em vista o formato de 24h. A lógica pode ser tanto em PHP quanto em MYSQL, já que de qualquer forma deve parar uma Stored Procedure.

Ex:

```
Inicio   - Fim       Busca      Esta no intervalo?
07:00:00 - 09:00:00  08:00:00   Sim
19:00:00 - 22:00:00  23:00:00   Não
18:00:00 - 03:00:00  01:00:00   Sim
```

Isso sem depender de qualquer data. Apenas intervalo de horas mesmo.

[Este tópico](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/98404/como-verificar-se-minha-hora-atual-est%C3%A1-em-um-intervalo-de-hora) quase resolve, mas não entendi que 01:00:00 está no intervalo de 18h as 03h, por exemplo.

Comment: 01:00:00 está no intervalo informado, sim, ora.   Das 18h da tarde às 03h da manhã, e o 01:00:00 significa que é 1 da manhã/madrugada. 

Se você quer checar 1 da tarde, então deve informar 13:00:00

Comment: Isso não resolve?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070116/php-check-if-date-between-two-dates

Answer (score 3):

#### Solução em PHP

Ao meu ver, já que estamos trabalhando com horários, o mais fácil é utilizar a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.datetime.php) do PHP. Primeiro, vamos definir os testes mostrados no enunciado:

```
$tests = [
  [
    "inicio" => "07:00:00", 
    "final"  => "09:00:00",
    "busca"  => "08:00:00",
    "saida"  => true
  ],[
    "inicio" => "19:00:00", 
    "final"  => "22:00:00",
    "busca"  => "23:00:00",
    "saida"  => false
  ],[
    "inicio" => "18:00:00", 
    "final"  => "03:00:00",
    "busca"  => "01:00:00",
    "saida"  => true
  ],
];
```

Os três testes propostos, composto pelo horário inicial, final, o de busca e a saída esperada. Para executar os testes, utilizamos um *loop* básico:

```
foreach($tests as $test)
{
    // ...
}
```

Primeiro passo é definir os objetos referentes aos horários:

```
foreach($tests as $test)
{
  $ininio = new DateTime($test["inicio"]);
  $final  = new DateTime($test["final"]);
  $busca  = new DateTime($test["busca"]);
}
```

Como no enunciado fica claro que deverá ser independente do dia e que, inclusive, o intervalo pode iniciar-se em um dia e terminar em outro, como é o caso do terceiro teste, precisamos fazer uma verificação simples: se o horário final for menor que o inicial, acrescente ao final um intervalo de um dia.

```
foreach($tests as $test)
{
  $ininio = new DateTime($test["inicio"]);
  $final  = new DateTime($test["final"]);
  $busca  = new DateTime($test["busca"]);

  if ($final <= $inicio) {
    $final->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
  }
}
```

Leia mais sobre a classe [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.dateinterval.php) na documentação. Desta forma, se o horário final for menor que o inicial, é acrescentado 24h nele, passando a ser o mesmo horário do dia seguinte.

A mesma lógica se aplica ao horário buscado: se ele for inferior ao horário inicial, ele deve ser considerado como do dia seguinte e, portanto, ser acrescentado 24h também.

```
foreach($tests as $test)
{
  $ininio = new DateTime($test["inicio"]);
  $final  = new DateTime($test["final"]);
  $busca  = new DateTime($test["busca"]);

  if ($final <= $inicio) {
    $final->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
  }

  if ($busca <= $inicio) {
    $busca->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
  }
}
```

Com isso, basta verificar o intervalo:

```
foreach($tests as $test)
{
  $ininio = new DateTime($test["inicio"]);
  $final  = new DateTime($test["final"]);
  $busca  = new DateTime($test["busca"]);

  if ($final <= $ininio) {
    $final->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
  }

  if ($busca <= $ininio) {
    $busca->add(new DateInterval("P1D"));
  }

  if ($busca >= $ininio && $busca <= $final) {
    echo "Sim";
  } else {
    echo "Não";
  }

  echo ", esperado " . ($test["saida"] ? "sim" : "não") . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Eu acrescentei à mensagem de saída o valor esperado para cada teste, para servir de comparação. Ao executar o código, teremos a saída:

```
Sim, esperado sim
Não, esperado não
Sim, esperado sim
```

> Veja o código funcionando em [Repl.it](https://repl.it/G3PU/0) ou no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/93xXDr).

Comment: Incrível o poder de DateTime(). Muito obrigado Anderson e aos demais.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, esse caso é um pouco mais simples se você fixar um modelo de horas, se você estiver utilizando o modelo de 24hrs (que o relógio começa as 00h e vai até as 23h) ai basta você contar apenas as horas, vamos imaginar o seguinte:

1. Você tem duas strings, o intervalo inicial e o intervalo final, digamos 07:00 e 09:00.
2. Quebre por ":" você vai obter dois arrays, o primeiro será `Array([0] => '07', [1] => '00')` e o segundo será `Array([0] => '09', [1] => '00')`.
3. Você terá um terceiro array que será a hora que o usuário está procurando. Faça o mesmo com ele
4. Primeiramente verifique as horas. `Se horaUsuario >= horaInicio E horaUsuario <= horaFim` então a hora está no intervalo, o mesmo vale para os minutos. Encadeie 2 `if` para fazer o primeiro caso e o segundo de forma independente, deste jeito se o usuário já não tiver as horas ele nem vai fazer a segunda condição.

Também existe a possibilidade de usar o objeto de datas do próprio PHP, como neste tópico: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351981/php-hours-difference-hhmm-format

Answer (score 0):

Sim, neste caso, 07:00 as 09:00,

```
Se horaUsuario >= horaInicio E horaUsuario <= horaFim
```

atenderia a necessidade. Porém, o problema é quando passa da 0h... imagine o período ser

```
22:00 - 02:00
```

a busca por '01:00' não funcionaria, por a hora (pesquisando por número) seria menor do que 22h.

Comment: Isso é uma solução pra pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Quando escrevi a pergunta, acreditei que apenas com a lógica seria possível resolver este abacaxi, mas não consegui. Através do código do Anderson quase resolvi, mas falta uns detalhes. O caso real é este: não pode existir no banco um registro com período sobrepondo outro, ou seja, se la tiver '07:00:00' como hora inicial e '09:00:00' final, não poderia ser adicionado nenhum outro período coincidisse com este período. Portanto '06:00:00' as '10:00:00' não poderia ser inserido durantes as 24 horas do dia, isso independente do dia.

Desde já agradeço pelo apoio pessoal.

Comment: Assim muda completamente o problema. Sugiro que abra outra pergunta e deixe bem claro qual a sua necessidade. Alterar a pergunta aqui irá invalidar todas as respostas já dadas.