# Ajuda em lógica para não sobrepor uma faixa de horários já existe na base

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia. Conforme sugerido por um membro da comunidade, [no post que deu início a este](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/191131/d%C3%BAvida-com-l%C3%B3gica-como-descobrir-se-uma-hora-est%C3%A1-entre-o-intervalo-de-horas-i), venho pedir a colaboração em uma lógica. Tenho uma tabela que contém os campos **hora_inicio** e **hora_termino**. Preciso de uma rotina que impossibilite o usuário de inserir uma faixa de horário que venha sobrepor outros já existentes, independente do dia. Poderá, portanto, ser inserida qualquer faixa de horário entre as 24 horas. Imagine que a tabela esteja preenchida com estes valores:

```
   inicio        termino
1) '07:00:00' - '09:00:00'
2) '09:00:00' - '11:30:00'
3) '12:00:00' - '15:35:00'
4) '22:35:00' - '01:49:00'
```

O conjunto de parâmetros abaixo não poderia ser inseridos, pois sobrepõem os horários já existentes.

```
Não poderia ser inserido:
   inicio        termino
1) '07:00:01' - '08:00:00'
2) '10:00:00' - '11:32:00'
3) '06:00:00' - '23:00:00'
```

Resumindo, um horário não pode sobrepor um já existente.

Gostaria de criar uma instrução SQL ou uma Stored Procedure que retornasse true ou false, dizendo se pode ou não inserir a faixa de horários enviada pelos parâmetros inicio e termino. Os horários abaixo poderiam ser inseridos:

```
   inicio        termino
1) '06:00:00' - '06:30:00'
2) '11:30:00' - '12:00:00'
3) '15:35:00' - '16:12:00'
```

Uma observação importante é que pode ser inserido uma faixa de horário iniciando no mesmo horário em que termina outro já cadastrado. Pode ficar desta forma:

```
   inicio        termino
1) '06:00:00' - '12:00:00'
2) '12:00:00' - '18:00:00'
3) '18:00:00' - '00:00:00'
4) '00:00:00' - '06:00:00'
```

Agradeço desde já o apoio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode verificar cada horário utilizando a clausula `BETWEEN` do banco de dados. Para tratar corretamente datas em que o horário de inicio é inferior ao final, devemos adicionar um periodo.

Veja um exemplo:

```
SELECT
COUNT(*) AS qtd

FROM tempo
WHERE TIME_TO_SEC('23:52:00') BETWEEN 
TIME_TO_SEC(inicio) AND 

(TIME_TO_SEC(termino) + IF(inicio > termino, 24 * 60 * 60, 0))
```

O segredo da consulta está em converter os horários para segundos com a função `TIME_TO_SEC`. O tratamento dos horários menores é feito somando-se mais um dia (em segundos) ao tempo total.

Para verificar corretamente o valor, devemos ter uma consulta para cada um dos parâmetros informados, e a contagem final deve retornar um valor zerado. Um exemplo completo e funcional da sobreposição:

```
SET @inicio = '06:00:00';
SET @termino = '10:00:00';

SET @inicioSegundos = TIME_TO_SEC(@inicio);
SET @terminoSegundos = TIME_TO_SEC(@termino);

/* A clausula BETWEEN inclui o valor do inicio, portanto podemos adicionar 1 segundo para evitar este problema */
SET @inicioSegundos = @inicioSegundos + 1;

SET @umDia = 24 * 60 * 60;

SELECT
COUNT(*) qtd
FROM tempo
WHERE 
  (@inicioSegundos  BETWEEN TIME_TO_SEC(inicio) AND (TIME_TO_SEC(termino) + IF(inicio > termino, @umDia, 0)))
OR
  (@terminoSegundos BETWEEN TIME_TO_SEC(inicio) AND (TIME_TO_SEC(termino) + IF(inicio > termino, @umDia, 0)))
OR
  (TIME_TO_SEC(inicio)  BETWEEN @inicioSegundos AND (@terminoSegundos + IF(@inicioSegundos > @terminoSegundos, @umDia, 0)))
OR
  (TIME_TO_SEC(termino) BETWEEN @inicioSegundos AND (@terminoSegundos + IF(@inicioSegundos > @terminoSegundos, @umDia, 0)))
OR
  (TIME_TO_SEC(inicio) = TIME_TO_SEC(termino))
```

Para este exemplo estou considerando a seguinte estrutura de dados:

```
CREATE TABLE tempo(
  inicio TIME NOT NULL,
  termino TIME NOT NULL
);

insert into tempo(inicio, termino)
VALUES
('07:00:00' , '09:00:00'),
('11:00:00' , '11:30:00'),
('12:00:00' , '15:35:00'),
('23:50:00' , '03:30:00')
```

### Edit 22/03/2017

Adicionei um tratamento especial para o caso de haver um horário para o dia inteiro, por exemplo, inicio = 10:00:00 e termino = 10:00:00.

Adicionei também um tratamento para ignorar o horário de inicio na clausura `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Só tem o problema de virar o dia dentro do intervalo, por exemplo, de 23:00:00 até 01:00:00. Se verificar o horário 23:30:00, a consulta traria `qtd` igual a 0.

Comment: Justamente isso. O problema é quando virar o dia. Ai que está o abacaxi!

Comment: jlHertel, mas lembrando que são 2 parâmetros que devem ser checados com os campos inicio e termino da tabela. Descobrir se um horário está entre inicio e termino foi tranquilo, graças a ajuda do @AndersonCarlosWoss. Mas e quando são 2 parâmetros de entrada?

Comment: Basta fazer a mesma lógica para o horário final e juntar as cláusulas. Veja o que foi feito na resposta e tenta aí.

Comment: Certo. Isso resolve o problema de saber se a busca esta entra inicio e fim, seja a busca do parametro de inicio quanto do final. A dúvida agora é sabe se há um valor que sobrepoem... faça um teste.. mantenha somente o valor <pre>'07:00:00' - '09:00:00'</pre> na tabela e imagine que se esta inserindo <pre>'06:00:00' - '10:00:00'</pre>... de acordo com este Select, será permitido esta inserção!

Comment: @jlHertel, que script fantástico este que vc fez. Fiz uns testes mas ele ainda deixa acrescentar estes valores:  00h00 às 00h00, 00h01 às 00h01, 00h02 às 00h02. Onde será que tem que alterar para que não possibilite isso? Só ressaltando (isso eu ia tentar mudar aqui), que um horário inicial pode ser o mesmo do horario final, ou seja, pode haver 10h00 às 11h00, das 11h00 as 15h37, 15h37 às 22h49.. ou seja, de repente o usuário pode definer que este período seja as 24h... das 0h as 0h. Será que complica muito?

Comment: Ah sim... é que sou novo por aqui, e ainda não entendo muito bem como funciona. O placeholder do textarea diz "Use comentários para pedir mais informações ou sugerir melhorias.", por isso me referi aqui à melhoria quanto ainda poder inserir sobrepondo horários e do detalhe de que um novo registro poder ter a hora inicial sendo a mesmo horário final de um registro já existente. Será que é melhor criar uma nova pergunta?

Comment: @jlHertel, editei a pergunta. Agora entendi. É bacana manter uma página mais enxuta com uma pergunta e uma resposta objetiva! Desde já agradeço.

Comment: @Leco, adicionei mais dois tratamentos para os casos de ter uma hora que ocupe o dia inteiro e também para o caso das horas iniciais e finais iguais. *Nota*: Vou apagar alguns dos comentários desta resposta, para não ficar tão poluído para futuros leitores.

Comment: @jlHertel, fiz os testes, e a única coisa que 'deu problema' é a seguinte, por exemplo, se adicionar '09:00:00' - '10:00:00', '10:00:00' - '11:00:00', '11:00:00' - '12:00:00', vai tranquilo. Porém, se adicionar '08:00:00' - '09:00:00' já tendo das '09:00:00' - '10:00:00' ele não permite. Parece que ele permite quando a hora é maior do que a ja tem... Deu pra entender?

Comment: @Leco, a idéia é exatamente a mesma do tratamento de inicio. O que acontece se você subtrair 1 segundo do tempo final? Em tese isso resolveria seu problema.

Comment: @jlHertel, entendi. Deu certinho. Havia passado dias pensando nessa rotina. Vc me ajudou demais. Não sei como agradecer. Aprendi muito com vc e esse seu 'select cabuloso'. Muito obrigado por tudo e um forte abraço.